# compare SQL and LINQ for Joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, join

I have a query in SQL as below : (This query works as expected)

```
select sender.Name from Members sender, Relationships relation, StatusMaster s
where
sender.MemberID = relation.RequestSenderID and
relation.StatusID = s.StatusID and 
s.Status = 'Allowed' and
( relation.RequestReceiverID = 3)
```

I have some basic knowledge of LINQ. But I am really struggling with joins.

I have tried to convert above query to LINQ. Here is the LINQ Query :

```
var members = from member in db.Members
              join relation in db.RelationShips
              on member.MemberID equals relation.RequestSenderID
              join status in db.StatusMasters
              on relation.StatusID equals status.StatusID
              where
              status.Status == "Allowed" && relation.RequestReceiverID == 3
              select member.Name;
```

But I get an error while trying to convert members to the JSON object.
The error is : An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. **EntityCommandExecutionException**

So, I copied the SQL generated by Visual Studio and pasted it in SQL Server Management Studio. There I noticed that `StatusMasters`(Table Name) is creating Problems. Name of the original table is `StatusMaster` and Entity Framework makes it pluralize.

I dont want to pluralize it, Then how can I stop entity framework from pluralizing that.

**Note :** The models are not auto-generated.

Comment: Can you post the inner exception from the EntityCommandExecutionException?

Comment: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.StatusMasters'."}

Comment: You mentioned the entities are not auto-generated. Do you define them manually? Can you change the name to `StatusMaster` at that time?

Comment: The name of the class file is `StatusMaster.cs` What else should I change?

Comment: Did you make this class? Or was it created by the designer? In other words, are you using code-first or database-first?

Comment: Did you mean to use `relation.RequestReceiverID` or `relation.RequestSenderID`? Your two code samples are in disagreement on that property.

Comment: I dont like designer to generate my code so, I created the class

Comment: Oh! I cleared that, Forgot to update in the question.

Comment: Can't you just replace `join status in db.StatusMasters` with `join status in db.StatusMaster`?

Comment: No, I get a compilation error.